# How to convert char value to int?

Tags: c++, char, integer, int

At the end I want to multiply int by char and this is impossible.How to get x value like a integer?

```
{
char a[50];
int y;
    printf("Vyvedete imeto si i razberete koe e shtastlivoto vi chislo\n");
    cin >> a;
int x = printf(a) * 5;
    printf(" Your lucky number is %d\n", x);
    printf("But wait! There is more!\n Type another number!\n");
    cin >> y;
    printf(y*x);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: This `int x = printf(a) * 5;` certainly doesn't whatever you think it does.

Comment: It's unclear what kind of conversion you want. Do you perhaps want to convert a string (a bit of text) to a number (stored in an integer)? With that, you should be able to easily locate hundreds of examples online.

Comment: This `printf(y*x);` provokes undefined behaviour, as a `const char *` is expected.

Comment: I tryed to find an answer but they dont help me.Maybe my knowledge is very little. My first printf basically asks for a name and since names are letters I use a variable "char a " for them.Then since I want to get the number of letters in the name I use int for x, and since x is an integer or some number, I try to get a nother number from the user and multiply x and y together, but it gives me an error which says - Error 1 error C2664: 'int printf(const char *,...)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const char *'

Comment: @StanimirQuid , So, you want `x` to have the value `length of string x*5`?

Comment: I want the X to have the value of the leght of the string a * 5.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this: ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char c='d';
    printf("the character before multiplication is %c and ascii representation is %d",c,c);
    int x=c*5;
    printf("the character after multiplication is %c and ascii representation is %d",x,x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to convert char value to int in C?

A `char` **is** an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

...

char c = 'A';
printf("%d\n", c);

int i = c;
printf("%d\n", i);

i = 'B';
printf("%d\n", i);

c = i; /* For this you might get warned about loosing 
          significant digits during conversion as 
          char is 8 bit wide and int is wider. */
printf("%d\n", c);
```

prints

```
65
65
66
66
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
char a[50]=""; //initialize a
printf("Vyvedete imeto si i razberete koe e shtastlivoto vi chislo\n");
cin >> a; //better to use fgets/scanf
int x = strlen(a) * 5; //use strlen from string.h to get the length of a
printf(" Your lucky number is %d\n", x);
```

Note that mixing C style code with C++ is a bad practice. Either use `cout` and `cin` or `printf` and `scanf`. Also note that you need to include `string.h`(`cstdlib` for C++) if you want to use the `strlen` function. And using the `string` datatype is recommended if you are using C++.

Comment: Thank you for opening my eyes, because I had no idea that I am mixing them even tho I knew that the functions I use are mixes c with c++.
I will try your suggestion and be more careful next time. My stupid question is a product of my lack of knowledge and patience.